# class.getResource() within Java-EE (wildfly)

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly

I am using Java-EE (Wildfly v.17)

I want to access the file "config.txt" which resides within `WEB-INF/classes/config.txt`.

I know one solution with `servletContext`.

**However, I am wondering why something common does NOT work:**

```
// prints: file:/Users/test/server/wildfly-17.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/as/ejb3/main/timers/
// why does this point to "ejb3/main/timers" ???
log.info(User.class.getResource("/").toExternalForm());
```

Nothing of those works, I always get `java.lang.NullPointerException` (no file found, but the file is there!)

```
var resource = User.class.getResource("/config.txt");


var resource = User.class.getResource("/WEB-INF/classes/config.txt")


var resource = User.class.getResource("config.txt")


var resource = getClass().getResource("config.txt")


var resource = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("config.txt")
```

**How can I use `getResource()` or `getResourceAsStream()` within Wildfly?**

(Or where should I put the `config.txt` to be able to use `getResource()` ?)

Comment: The first version should work. If it doesn't, the file isn't there. Explicitly naming `WEB-INF/classes` is definitely wrong, as is omitting the `/`, unless the file is in the same package as the `User` class or the current class respectively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to get access to the data in your `WEB-INF/classes/config.txt` file is to use [java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream("/config.txt")](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-), which is covered by your first example.

If this returns `null` then the file is not present. If you're building with Maven then the most common reason for this is placing `config.txt` in the `src/main/java` directory instead of `src/main/resources`.

Attempts to use [java.lang.Class.getResource("/config.txt")](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) will end in disappointment because the URL that is returned will likely contain a scheme that is tricky or impossible to use, such as "jar://..." or "vfs://...". You cannot rely upon WildFly to return a "file://.." style of URL for a class-loader resource.

Comment: Thanks. `User.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.txt")` works.

Comment: One note: `getResourceAsStream("config.txt")`, searches relative to the classpath root by default. So no need to add the file separator at the beginning `("/config.txt")`.

Comment: ok, my fault. I did use `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`, so I did not need the file separator at the beginning. There is a no difference between `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` and `getClass()getResource()`, both defaults to relative to the .class file. But `ClassLoader.getResource()` searches relative to the classpath by default.

Answer (score 1):

Jboss AS7 or wildfly use its internal module structure during class loading mechanism , so when you call getResource method to load the file (external file), it tries to load the file using ejb3 module ( ) and the ejb3 module try to load the file from timers folder

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5" name="org.jboss.as.ejb3">
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
    </properties>

    <resources>
        <artifact name="${org.wildfly:wildfly-ejb3}"/>
        **<resource-root path="timers" />**
    </resources>
```

You can try the below suggestions :-

- move your configuration file under timers folder
- create your module and force jboss to load the classes from your module, you can find the steps inside the following link "https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToPutAnExternalFileInTheClasspath"
- move your configuration file under resource folder "src/main/resources" and load it as resource stream

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions which all work. However best solution in my case is to use resource stream.

Comment: Funnily enough I am the author of "How to put an external file in the classpath".

Comment: for the third suggestion "...load it as resource stream...",  could you elaborate how to do it?